# How can I detect the key pressed on an iPhone keyboard using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to detect if the backspace key has been pressed on the iPhone keyboard. The logic I wrote works perfectly on android, but not on iPhone or the iPhone simulator.

this is my code:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
          child: RawKeyboardListener(
            onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
            if(event.runtimeType == RawKeyDownEvent){
              if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace || event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
                _focusNodes[i]?.unfocus();
                if (i != 0) {
                  _focusNodes[i - 1]?.requestFocus();
                }
              }
            }
          },
            focusNode: FocusNode(),
            child: TextField(
               key: Key('PinInput'),
              controller: TextEditingController(),
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

This piece of code works perfectly in android, but the `onKey` callback in the **RawKeyboardListener** is not being called when I hit a key in an iPhone or iPhone simulator.

How do I handle this?

Comment: I´m not quite sure what exactly you are looking for. But if you want to detect whether the keyboard is open you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility).

Comment: @JahnE. I am trying t detect the exact key pressed (backspace key) on the keyboard IOS. I want to perform a logic when the backspace key is pressed.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: same issue here any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the flutter api, **LogicalKeyboardKeys** like you are using in your code **are not supported on iOS**. Learn more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/kIosToLogicalKey-constant.html).

You can use the map to "translate" the **iOS key codes** to your expected LogicalKeyboardKey. In this map you will find that the iOS key code 42 is what you are looking for: `42: LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace,`

To use the constant, `import package:flutter/services.dart.`

Then access the top-level constant **kIosToLogicalKey** in your if check like this:

```
if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace ||
    // TODO: Check if iOS key code is 42 or kIosToLogicalKey[42]  ||
    event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
```

FYI: I know that this is not the complete solution, however, I do not have a mac to test whether it is working anyways, but I hope this gives you the right direction to look at and go from there.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, per "... onKey callback in the RawKeyboardListener is not being called when I hit a key in an iPhone or iPhone simulator."